# ajax success only after images of my html request are load?

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

Any advice how i can do it via jQ?
I would like to success only when all images too are ready..
thnks

```
 $.ajax(
    {
        url: myUrl,
        type: 'post',
        data: postData,
        success: function (resp)
        {
            $('#content').html($('#content', resp).html());
        }
    });
```

thnks

Comment: You need to go to other questions you have asked, and choose one of the answers on each of them and mark it as accepted (the big checkmark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, you will need the [special image load event plug-in](https://github.com/peol/jquery.imgloaded/raw/master/ahpi.imgload.js). Otherwise, the event will not fire if the image is already in the browser's cache.

Then put this code inside your success handler:

```
var images = jQuery('#content img');
var imgcount = images.length;
images.load(function() {
    imgcount--;
    if (imgcount < 1) alert('All images are loaded.');
});
```

Please take the time to mark answers to your questions as Accepted, by clicking the checkmark next to the one you think is best. Thanks. :-)